# Partition Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following equivalence:

"Let $X$ be a set and $R$ be a partition of $X$, this is:

i) $(\forall A,B \in R, A \neq B) \colon A \cap B = \emptyset$

ii) $ \bigcup_{A \in R} A = X$

We say that a topology $\tau$ on $X$ comes from is a partition topology iff $\tau = \tau(R)$ for some partition $R$ of $X$.

Then a topology $\tau$ is a partition topology iff every open set in $\tau$ is also a closed set."

I am trying to proove $\Leftarrow$. I have tried using Zorn to proove the existance of a kind of maximal refinement of $\tau$ so as to find the partition that could generate $\tau$ but I am getting nowhere. I would truly appreciate any help posible...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that if $U$ is connected then $U$ doesn't contain open sets (besides itself and the empty set). Conclude the the partition $R$ to connected components is the wanted partition.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint: $R$ consists of the closures of the one-point sets.